# Can a windows 2008 R2 server join a 2003 domain?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain

I need to upgrade a windows server 2003 machine to at least 2003 R2. I'd like to upgrade it all the way to 2008 R2. I just wanted to verify, 2008 R2 can join 2003 domains right? The other servers are 2003.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as your existing domain is at least at Windows server 2000 native domain functional level and 2008 is only going to be a member server & not a domain controller, you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

We have two 2003 R2 DC servers and a few months ago I added a 2008 R2 DC, that works fine.
Our functional level is 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Sure can. The R2 machine is going to be a role server, and not a DC correct?