# Can Windows Server 2008 DC be added to a Windows Server 2003 domain without changing the schema?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain-controller

My production system has two Windows Server 2003 R2 servers acting as domain controllers.  Can I add a Windows Server 2008 DC to the existing  domain without changing the schema?  This is a similar question to [Can a windows 2008 R2 server join a 2003 domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/118774/can-a-windows-2008-r2-server-join-a-2003-domain) but in that case, the 2008 server being added was not a domain controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The process for adding a 2008 DC **requires** schema updates. Member servers are not a problem, but a Domain Controller is another thing entirely.

That said, generally speaking schema updates like those that come with Server 2008 are harmless to lower versions. Do you have a specific problem with the schema updates that come with 2008?

Comment: I'm fairly confident that schema updates are always backwards-compatible.  The only problem would stem from an application that checks for the domain level as an 'equals' ("=") rather than a 'greater-than-or-equal' ("<=") (as in 'domain level is 2003 native' rather than 'at least 2003').

Comment: @gwaldo It's schema version, not Functional Level. The Schema gets updated the moment the right 'adprep' call is made, so you can have a 2008-level schema but still 2003 functional level. If @Knox is concerned about schema issues, functional level doesn't matter.

Comment: You're quite right.

Comment: well, I was pretty sure that nothing would care if I did upgrade the schema, but if I could avoid it until I actually needed, I would probably hold off.  We don't run any apps other than Windows clients that are aware of AD so fortunately it's very low risk to upgrade the schema.